# Image doesn't appear on MYSQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, image

My problem is that if i try to post a image trought my website to my database called photos they don't appear there. Images do appear inside the folder i created upload/img. My database photos table is called images with 2 rows. id int(11) and image MEDIUMBLOB. Any ideas why doesn't my images appear on my MYSQL database?

```
    <?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Image Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
  <?php if(isset($_SESSION['err'])){ ?>
    <h2><?php echo $_SESSION['err']; ?></h2>
  <?php session_unset(); } ?>
  <form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input type="file" name="image" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="save">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My upload.php

```
<?php

require_once('config.php');
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['save']))
{
  $target_dir = "upload/img/";
  $filename = explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name']);
  $ext = $filename[1];
  $imgname = time().'.'.$ext;
  $target_file = $target_dir . $imgname ;
 if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
      $path=$imgname;
      $conn->query("INSERT INTO images (id, image)VALUES ('$path')");
      $_SESSION["Success"]='Image Is Upload Success...';
      header("Location:view.php"); /* Redirect browser */
      exit();
    } else {
      $_SESSION["err"]=$text;
      header("Location:index.php"); /* Redirect browser */
      exit();
    }
  }
}

?>
```

Here is picture of my "images" table.

[image]

Comment: You're not providing an ID in the INSERT statement, might be something to do with it. Try outputting the errors from the mysql.

Comment: Depends on what value ID is.  If it's simply an AUTO INCREMENT value, I don't think he needs to specify it at all.  If it's a string identifier of some type, then you'd need to pass in a value which he's not doing.

Comment: I removed the id row from my table and then i could upload the image but this isn't the exact solution i am looking for because it gave me an error after uploading the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured it out why those pictures wont upload to my MYSQL database.

1. Like some people here suggested i didn't need "id" written in my INSERT part.
2. My table id row had to be set to primary and AUTO_INCREMENT(see image below).

[image]

Now things seem to be working fine. You can set image row type from varchar to blob.

Answer (score 1):

it has to be

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
  $path=$imgname;
  $conn->query("INSERT INTO images (image) VALUES ('$path')");
  $_SESSION["Success"]='Image Is Upload Success...';
  header("Location:view.php"); /* Redirect browser */
  exit();
} else {
  $_SESSION["err"]=$text;
  header("Location:index.php"); /* Redirect browser */
  exit();
}
```

because you are telling Mysql to insert id but you didn't provide it's value

Comment: I replaced $conn->query("INSERT INTO images (id, image)VALUES ('$path')"); with $conn->query("INSERT INTO images (image) VALUES ('$path')"); but the outcome is same. It doesn't upload the image to my database but image appears in my folder every time.